# Marketplace Test Kit incorrectly claims ID_CAP_MICROPHONE

Tags: windows-phone-7, app-hub

I am running the Marketplace Test Kit in preperation for submission to the Marketplace and the automated tests is claiming I am using `ID_CAP_NETWORKING` and `ID_CAP_MICROPHONE`.  I am not using the microphone or any audio code anywhere within the application.

I have double checked the references/code for the items listed in the Rules.xml in the SDK folder and cannot find any reference to any of them.

Why is the Marketplace Test Kit claiming that the application requires `ID_CAP_MICROPHONE`?

Comment: do you use any 3rd party dlls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to `ID_CAP_MICROPHONE` appear on you app, you or a 3rd party component must have a reference to [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.Microphone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.microphone.aspx).

So either remove your code that references that class or the 3rd party component that does!

Comment: You make it sound so simple! Used CheckASM to find that it's the third party package WPExtensions which has the reference which I'm using for a bindable application bar. Luckily the source is available so I rebuilt without the Microphone helper code and now all is well. Ta!

Comment: You could always have gone with Reflector too! ;)